# How to construct a side-by-side boxplot from a frequency table?

Tags: r

Data looks like this:

```
lagmonth | amt    | table
1       |  4795.5 | a
2       |  1999.4 | a
3       |  540.2   | a
...
```

Table column has two variables, a and b. lagmonth column has integer values of 1 through 36. I would like to construct a side-by-side boxplot with x axis of table (a and b), and y axis of lagmonth using amt values as weight (or frequency?) of lagmonth values. How do I do this on R?

```
> ggplot(dfx, aes(dfx$table, dfx$lagmonth, weights = max(0,dfx$amt)))  + geom_boxplot()
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_boxplot()`:
object 'weight' not found
```

This didn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, you don't need to include the `df$...` within the `aes()`-function. You can state it like this: `.., aes(table, lagmonth), `.
Second: what exactly do you want to do with the weights?

Comment: @David Thank you for your advice and your question. Each row has a unique lagmonth and table combination, so there are 72 rows only. The weights are supposed to be used like frequency, so if they were round numbers, such as (1 | 4795 | a), it would mean there are 4795 rows with "1"s and "a"s in the data. I hope this clarifies my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot(dfx, aes(x=table, y=amt)) + geom_boxplot()